# injected statless bean into managed bean gives nullpointer

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, managed-bean, stateless

I have a ManagedBean that getts a stateless bean injected but it always gives me a nullpointer for the injection. What am I doing wrong here? (I´m learning JSF and its just an example so please ignore the naming of classes etc)

There a two different jars (web.jar and services.jar)

managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HelloPB
{
    @Inject
    private ExamServiceBase examService;

    private String name = "";

    public String getName()
    {
        Exam exam = examService.getSingleExam();
        return exam.getName();
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        //this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHello()
    {
        if ( name == null || name.length() < 1 )
        {
            return null;
        }
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

stateless bean

```
@Stateless
public class ExamServiceBase implements ExamService{

    @PersistenceContext(name="QuestifyPersistUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Exam getExam(String id){
        return em.find(Exam.class, id);
    }

    public Exam getSingleExam(){
        return em.find(Exam.class, "9E69F3EE-AE9E-4D53-B531-35504EDA450F");
    }   
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="body">
    </h:outputScript>
    <h1>JSF 2 Demo</h1>
    <h:form>

        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloPB.name}">
            <f:ajax render="helloTextOutput" />
        </h:inputText>

        <h:commandButton value="Say Hi via Ajax">
            <f:ajax execute="name" render="helloTextOutput" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:outputText id="helloTextOutput" value="#{helloPB.hello}" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Comment: ExamServiceBase is an EJB, so have you tried to inject it through EJB annotation? I am not sure it works with Inject...

Comment: @perissf, it works and it's perfectly legal. @Martin, is `ExamService` an `@Local` interface? You should try injecting with that if it is

Comment: @kolossus I do have a local interface and that was what I used originaly but neither that or my actual implemention works. Both give nullpointer exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure initially that you have a file WEB-INF/beans.xml in your application. It can be an empty file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
```

Then try to use the injected Bean from a postcostruct method. In my case it worked in this way.

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
Exam exam = examService.getSingleExam();
}
```

Comment: I will try this out later today, however, this realy seem like a hack and not a solid solution. =

Comment: I will try this later today, however, it seems like a hack. Any reason why this would work? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Marthin, it's not a hack but actually a requirement for CDI to work. You must have the beans.xml file in the WEB-INF of your web-app(if applicable) for injection to work

Comment: I have added the beans.xml file. Still the same problem. Any more idee´s?